# What is the intended input method to ANSI C Second Edition exercise problems?

Tags: c

I am doing Kernighan/Ritchie ANSI C Second Edition exercises in the first chapter. Problem is, the book didn't teach you yet about argv/argc or fopen, yet it uses such a structure where if you just run your program and give input at runtime, you will get into an infinite repetition of the test `(c = getchar()) != EOF` because getchar() at runtime will prompt the user for input as soon stdin is empty, and when the user gives input, the input will process, and getchar() will prompt for another input. EOF will literally never get encountered.

My mentors told me that you can input an EOF with ctrl+d, but that is obviously a hack and not intended.

Another solution they gave me is `a.out <<< "some string"` which actually works and does have EOF, but now I am at a point where I have to have an input of multiple lines, and I have no idea how to input lines like this, and frankly I heard that <<< didn't even exist in 1989.

Here is a code example of the type of problem:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/* count characters in input; 1st version */ 
int main() 
{ 
    long nc; 

    nc = 0; 
    while (getchar() != EOF) 
        ++nc; 
    printf("%ld\n", nc); 
}
```

So how did programmers feed input in this kind of program back in the day? Mind you, you are only allowed to use the things the book taught you until now (which is literally nothing about input)

Comment: `Ctrl+d` (Linux) and `Ctrl-z` (Windows) are not a "hack". They close the `stdin` input stream. The program will also encounter `EOF` if a file is redirected as input.

Comment: `EOF` is a **signal** ... much like when you ask a girl what is her age and she answers "Go to hell". "Go to hell" is a signal, not an age. The way to generate the `EOF` signal from the keyboard is to type Ctrl+D on Unix / Ctrl+Z on Windows (keyboards don't typically *"end"*).

Comment: You can redirect the contents of a file to the process which becomes its stdin.  Essentially `a.out < filename.ext`.  You should get EOF as a result.

Comment: The book is about C, not the operating system. The way you feed input to the program is an OS detail. The authors assumed that the programmers were familiar with the OS (at the time, this was almost exclusively Unix).

Comment: Back in the day they were using serial port terminals.  I imagine that the EOF character combination was set in termcap or something.  @Thomas Dickey would know for sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Comment: @WeatherVane: Control-D does not close the input stream. When the underlying software executes a read to get more characters from the terminal and receives none, it raises its EOF flag and returns `EOF` from `getchar` or whatever other input routine was called. Control-D sends the user’s currently typed data to the process. When Control-D is pressed twice in a row or after a return/enter, there is no data to send, so the read routine returns no characters. The resulting EOF flag is soft and can be cleared by `clearrr(stdin)`, after which more data may be read. The stream is not closed.

Comment: The "EOF" special terminal character could be changed from the default (ASCII EOT, Ctrl-D) using the `stty` command, which coincidentally was introduced into Unix at the same time as the first C compiler.

Comment: The authors absolutely intended you to just type away at the keyboard, and to hit control-D when finished.  This is no hack at all: it's how the Unix CLI and related systems fundamentally work.  I'm not sure why you feel this technique is in any way inferior.  (For what it's worth, it's something I still do every day.)

Comment: Since when is `Ctrl-D` a hack?